# Can't install older version of rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hello guys how can I install an older version of rmarkdown.
Below is my code to install the 1.8 version. But it outputs an error

```
> devtools::install_version("rmarkdown", version = "1.8", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
Error in package_find_repo(package, repos) : 
  couldn't find package 'rmarkdown'
```

Comment: I receive a 503 HTTP error code that means "Service unavailable" but I can copy and paste this url (http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rmarkdown/rmarkdown_1.8.tar.gz) and it works.. You can always install the package by yourself...

Comment: How can I install the .tar file?

Comment: Try to extract and copy-paste the 'rmarkdown' folder into R packages folder

Answer (score 0):

I have already resolved the issue I used the following code.
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)
install_version('rmarkdown', version = '1.8')